# Elasticsearch : Uncaught ReferenceError: elasticsearch is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I am trying to create a NodeJS application using Elasticsearch

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="../bower_components/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.js"></script>
<script>
function esPinger() {
    var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = elasticsearch.Client({
  host: 'localhost:9200',
  log: 'trace'
});

client.ping({
  // ping usually has a 3000ms timeout
  requestTimeout: Infinity,

  // undocumented params are appended to the query string
  hello: "elasticsearch!"
}, function (error) {
  if (error) {
    console.trace('elasticsearch cluster is down!');
  } else {
    console.log('All is well');
    alert("YAY");
  }
});
}
</script>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>NodeJS Starter Application</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <center>
    <button onclick="esPinger()">Ping ES</button>
    </center>
  </body>

</html>
```

i installed the elasticsearch client as

```
npm install elasticsearch
```

and also

```
bower install elasticsearch
```

in my project folder, i can see that there is a `bower_componenets` folder that has all of the .js files for elasticsearch, including `elasticsearch.js`

now, when i run my page and click on the button, i get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: elasticsearch is not defined
```

any idea why? am i missing some configuration?

for reference, here is what my project structure looks like

[image]

**Edit**

Here is what i see in the inspect element console

[image]

**how can it not get the library!**

Comment: you need to uncomment this line: `//var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');` by removing the leading forward slashes `//`

Comment: no effect. please see the edit

Answer (score 0):

Node.JS is a "server-side" technology, not a "browser" technology.
Thus, Node-specific calls, like:

```js
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
```

do not work in the browser.